# How to remove 1px in ItemsPanel on ListBox WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, padding, listboxitem

i can not found margin 1px in ListBox items panel.

my xaml code.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resource>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background">
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                       <UniformGrid Columns="2" Background="Red" Margin="0"/>
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resource>
</ListBox>
```

and result image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLLl.png)

i want to remove blue background!!
please help me!!

Comment: You can change this by providing a Template for ListBox.

Comment: You questions is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195668/remove-extra-space-around-listbox

Comment: Thank you. But that was not my question. Difference problem.

Comment: I want remove blue background.

Comment: Blue background is no margin no padding. And listbox, listboxitem all no margin no padding. That's link is not my question